# Invalid token '}' error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding my error here. I am trying to follow a tutorial to make a clicker game, but the error list keeps telling me I have an invalid token. Anyone got any ideas where I went wrong? Here is my coding so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEngine.UI.Text

}
```

Comment: the code is unfinished, needs at least something after UI.Text, and then a ; to close the statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not completed correctly.
You have declared a public member with a type but not a name. Try to add the name and end it with a semicolon. Here is the completed code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour {
    //fix this line
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text myText;

}
```

Invalid token '}' error is caused by semicolon or incomplete codes.